# Using loop to create multiple dropdownlistfor using different lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create multiple dropdownlistfor components like this:

```
if (Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox.Count; ++i)
        {
            var lista = Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox[i].Itens;
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <label>@Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox[i].Nome</label>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => m => m.CamposPreenchidosComboBox[i], new SelectList(lista), "Selecione", new { @id = "DDLUf", @class = "form-control field" })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox[i].Nome)
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    }
```

Each `dropdownlistfor` uses a list of objects stored inside `Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox[i].Itens`. Each object is defined like this:

```
 public class ItemCombobox
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
```

But i'm getting the "The type arguments for method cannot be inferred from the usage" error:

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor<TModel,TProperty>(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<TModel>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>, string, object)' cannot be inferred from the usage.
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making the list just a list of strings

```
var lista = Model.FilaChamado.CamposComboBox[i].Itens.Select(i => i.Descricao);
```

and make the drop down list bound to the strings

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => m => m.CamposPreenchidosComboBox[i].Name, new SelectList(lista), "Selecione", new { @id = "DDLUf"+i.ToString(), @class = "form-control field" })
```

Make sure to note the @Id should unique for each combobox, although I would recommend not setting this at all as it can mess with the ASP.NET Binding when there are lists of comboboxes. Maybe leave @Id out.

Comment: Worked for me! Also, i had to fix the x => m => m.CamposPreenchidosComboBox[i].Name to m => m.CamposPreenchidosComboBox[i].Name. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. Wish I understood your variable names, ha. Just going off syntax.